Stationarity Conditions VECM
Suppose we have a vector error correction model (VECM)
$$
\Delta y_{t}=\Pi y_{t-1}+\Gamma_{1}\Delta y_{t-1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\Gamma_{p-1}\Delta y_{t-p+1}+u_{t}
$$
A simple way to confirm that it is a stationary process is convert it to a VAR model
$$
y_{t} = \left(I+\Pi+\Gamma_{1}\right)y_{t-1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\left(\Gamma_{p-1}-\Gamma_{p-2}\right)y_{t-p+1}-\Gamma_{p-1}y_{t-p}+u_{t}
$$
find the eigenvalues of the companion matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
I+\Pi+\Gamma_{1} & \Gamma_{2}-\Gamma_{1} & \cdot\cdot\cdot & \Gamma_{p-1}-\Gamma_{p-2} & -\Gamma_{p-1}\\
I & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & I & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & I & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & I & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
and check whether any have a modulus greater than 1.
What I'm curious about is, suppose that we know for sure that the matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\Gamma_{1} & \cdot\cdot\cdot & \Gamma_{p-1}\\
I & 0 & 0\\
0 & I & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
does not have any eigenvalues with modulus greater than or equal to 1.
Based on that assumption, what assumptions would we have to make about $\Pi$ to ensure that the eigenvalues of the original companion matrix are not greater than one?
So in other words, we know that all the difference components together are stationary. What do we have to assume about $\Pi$ to ensure that we don't have the entire process explode?
My hope is that whatever conditions are required for $\Pi$ are independent of $\Gamma_{i}$.

I have done some simulations that suggest that the eigenvalues of the full companion matrix equals the eigenvalues of $/Pi$ and the eigenvalues of the difference companion matrix. That isn't really a proof though.That being said, this paper seems to provide a convincing enough proof: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/832256dg

Further simulation suggests that the what I said above is only true if $\Pi$ is full of zeros. In that case, the eigenvalues of the full companion matrix are N 1s along with the eigenvalues of the difference companion matrix. It doesn't hold more generally.

Based on some simulations, I found that that if $I+\Pi$ does not have any eigenvalues with modulus greater than 1, then the original companion matrix will not have eigenvalues with modulus greater than 1 (assuming the additional restrictions on the gamma companion matrix).
